# Javascript: Await in 'for .. in' loop for object not waiting for async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am currently working with the WP-API where I am creating pages from elements in my object. What I basically want to do is to iterate over the object, and for each element: create the page, get the pageID returned, save it to the element and proceed with the next element in the object.

However, what's currently happening is that it does not wait for the element to be finished creating the WP page.

I know this is a common question but I did not find an answer suitable to the 'for ... in ...' loop used.

That's my code rn:

```
async function checkContent(content) {
    let currentObj;
    for(const key in content) {
        currentObj = content[key][0];
        console.log(currentObj);
        currentObj.postId = await createPage(currentObj.title, currentObj.content);

    }
}


function createPage(title, content) {
    var wp = new WPAPI({
        endpoint: 'http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-json',
        username: 'admin',
        password: 'pass'
    });
    wp.pages().create({
        title: title,
        content: content,
        status: 'publish'
    })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error: ' + error.message);
        })
        .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.id);
        return response.id;
    })
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Am I not using 'await' correctly?

Comment: Like pointed out your not returning anything in createPage,.  But may I offer some suggestions for your createPage function,.  1. get rid of that catch, otherwise if there is an error, the calling function will not know, and continue.  2. If your going to use async,  might be any idea for you createPage to use it.. In this case you could just have do `return (await wp.page().create(....)).id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't return any Promise from `createPage` so there is nothing `await`  can wait for.

You have return the Promise chain create with `wp.pages().create`:

```
function createPage(title, content) {
  var wp = new WPAPI({
    endpoint: 'http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-json',
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'pass'
  });

  return wp.pages().create({
      title: title,
      content: content,
      status: 'publish'
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error: ' + error.message);
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.id);
      return response.id;
    })
}
```

Comment: hey, sorry for bother you again but I have extended my code slightly and now it seems to no longer wait again but I tried to do everything you said. Could you tell me one more time what I am doing wrong? here is my code snippet: https://js.do/code/asyncerror

Comment: @threxx SO is a Q&A platform so if you have a new problem then you have to create a new question for it. But your problem is that `fs.readFile`  a callback based asynchronous function and this doe snot return a Promise and you cant return from that callback using `return wp.pages().create` , you have to promisify `fs.readFile`.